# Make Google Custom Search look at GET parameters

Tags: get, arguments, google-custom-search

I have a Google Custom Search snippet in a page, say `search.php` and it seems to work fine if I use it from that page.

However, I'd need to somehow make it recognize GET arguments, so that for instance if I loaded `search.php?q=test`, it would directly search for test.

Is there a way to make it do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I can use [`CustomSearchControl`](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/js/cselement-reference#cse-el)'s  `execute` method.